# How to uniquely identify devices connected to com ports in a prolific USB to Serial hub?

Tags: serial-port, device-manager

I have a Joystick connected to USB to Serial Com port hub. In device manager it shows 4 listings,

> ```
> Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port(COM21) 
> Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port(COM22) 
> Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port(COM23) 
> Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port(COM24)
> ```

The machine is at remote location, so I couldn't check physically which port it is connected. So using remote desktop, is there any way to identify the COM port that Joystick is connected to?

Comment: No, serial port devices are very primitive and don't support plug & play.  Even if you were on-site, looking at it still doesn't tell you which port is being used.  Only trial-and-error works.  Trying to operate a joystick on a remote machine is inadvisable :)